# Can't connect to Ip addresses of hotspot connected devices using WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()

Tags: android, wifimanager

whenever I try to connect to the Ip I get from WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress(), I get java.net.ConnectException or NoRouteToHostException exception. Also, in the hot-spot providing device, it returns 0.0.0.0 when called WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress(). Can't seem to send any messages using any of the devices. And FYI, I used port 8080 and all the hotspot devices are above android 10.
Help please!
Thank you.

Comment: Please tell ip you got. And that ip would be of which device?

Comment: What kind of message do you wanna send? To whom? And why?

Comment: Solved it. I was trying to get the ip of the mobile hotspot providing device. I got it using DhcpInfo.gateaway. thank you everyone.